# Selecting polygons from file 1 based on their location within file 2 using ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, select-by-location

I'm working on a project right now where I want to find the census tracts within a particular traffic analysis district. I may just be blanking on it, but I'm working with two files. The first has census block/tract data, the second has the TAD data. I want to find all the polygons from file 1 that are contained within the each TAD polygon.

I'm just not finding recalling the ArcMap tool to use.

Answer (score 0):

Use Select by Location tool. You can refer here http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/using-select-by-location.htm